# SciChart cannot set Visibility on AxisMarker

Tags: xml, scichart

As you can read in the title, i can't set the Visibility Property of an AxisMarker in SciChart, although you can set the Opacity.

This would be the Class

```
<s:AxisMarkerAnnotation x:Class="PT.Modules.Infrastructure.CustomAxisMarker" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/scichart"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PT.Modules.Infrastructure" xmlns:progSettingServ="clr-namespace:PT.ProgramSettingsService;assembly=PT.ProgramSettingsService"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}" LabelTemplate="{DynamicResource AxisMarkerTemplate}"
    VerticalAnchorPoint="{Binding VerticalAnchor}" HorizontalAnchorPoint="{Binding HorizontalAnchor}" RenderTransformOrigin="{Binding RenderOrigin}"
    AnnotationCanvas="AboveChart" X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" IsHitTestVisible="False" d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
<s:AxisMarkerAnnotation.Resources>
```

AxisMarker Style

```
    <s:AxisMarkerAnnotation.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type s:AxisMarkerAnnotation}">
        <!--works-->
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        <!--won't work-->
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanChange, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Opacity)" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.75" AutoReverse="True"
                                    RepeatBehavior="5x" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type s:AxisMarkerAnnotation}},Path=DataContext.ProgramSettings.ChartSettings.Orientation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         Value="{x:Static progSettingServ:TouchMode.Wide}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</s:AxisMarkerAnnotation.Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the IsHidden Property instead the Visibility Property will work!

Comment: Yes this is a known 'issue' - the SciChart API uses Visibility internally to hide elements so use AnnotationBase.IsHidden to trigger visibility. For a full reasoning behind this see https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/annotations-visibility-bug